# Which files are updated when upgrading joomla?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, upgrade

I've been looking for the answer to this for ages now! Basically,I'm wondering which files will be changed when the joomla version is upgraded, i.e. what happens to any custom code- css, etc? Is it deleted and then has to be reimported by the admin from a backup, or does joomla preserve all this, and if so , which are the actual files it targets when doing the upgrade? Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the files changed by looking at the appropriate manual upgrade package. e.g. if going from 2.5.5 to 2.5.6 download and open this file:

http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/17174/74754/Joomla_2.5.5_to_2.5.6-Stable-Patch_Package.zip

Basically the upgrade packages don't delete custom code (assuming you haven't hacked the Joomla core). So everything in your template folder, like css, template php, js, core overrides, images, etc will be left alone. Your media will be left alone as well as it only replaces the changed core files.

Trev